# Reasoning behind having to specify L for long, F,D for float, double

Tags: java, variables, primitive-types

A few related questions here.

As per the title, why is it a requirement if we are specifying the variable type as long or float, double? Doesn't the compiler evaluate the variable's type at compile time?

Java considers all integral literals as `int` - is this to lessen the blow of inadvertent memory waste? And all floating-point literals as `double` - to ensure highest precision?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you have a constant there are subtle differences between value which look the same, but are not.  Additionally, since autoboxing was introduce, you get a very different result as less.

Consider what you get if you multiply 0.1 by 0.1 as a float or as a double and convert to a float.

```
float a = (float) (0.1 * 0.1);
float b = 0.1f * 0.1f;
System.out.println("a= "+new BigDecimal(a));
System.out.println("b= "+new BigDecimal(b));
System.out.println("a == b is " + (a == b));
```

prints

```
a= 0.00999999977648258209228515625
b= 0.010000000707805156707763671875
a == b is false
```

Now compare what you get if you use either `float` or `int` to perform a calculation.

```
float a = 33333333f - 11111111f;
float b = 33333333 - 11111111;
System.out.println("a= "+new BigDecimal(a));
System.out.println("b= "+new BigDecimal(b));
System.out.println("a == b is " + (a == b));
```

prints

```
a= 22222220
b= 22222222
a == b is false
```

Compare `int` and `long`

```
long a = 33333333 * 11111111; // overflows
long b = 33333333L * 11111111L;
System.out.println("a= "+new BigDecimal(a));
System.out.println("b= "+new BigDecimal(b));
System.out.println("a == b is " + (a == b));
```

prints

```
a= -1846840301
b= 370370362962963
a == b is false
```

compare `double` with `long`

```
double a = 333333333333333333L  / 333333333L;
double b = 333333333333333333D  / 333333333D;
System.out.println("a= "+new BigDecimal(a));
System.out.println("b= "+new BigDecimal(b));
System.out.println("a == b is " + (a == b));
```

prints

```
a= 1000000001
b= 1000000000.99999988079071044921875
a == b is false
```

In summary its possible to construct a situation where using `int`, `long`, `double` or `float` will produce a different result compared with using another type.

Answer (score 8):

This becomes important when you do more than a simple assignment. If you take

float x = 0.1 * 3.0;

it makes a difference if the computer does the multiplication in double precision and then converts to single precision or if it converts the numbers to single precision first and then multiplies.

edit:
Not in this explicit case 0.1 and 3.0, but if your numbers become complex enough, you will run into precision issues that show differences between float and double. Making it explicit to the compiler if they are supposed to be doubles or float avoids ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's simply to avoid confusion. How will the compiler know that 1.5 is meant to be a float or double if there's no default for it to fall back on?  As for evaluating variables, please note that variables != literals.

**Edit 1**
Regarding some comments, I believe that there are times when you wouldn't want the compiler to automatically translate the literal on the right to variable type on the left.

**Edit 2**
And of course there's

```
public void foo(int bar) {
  //...
}

public void foo(long bar) {
  //...
}

   //... some other method
   foo(20);  // which foo is called?
```

Comment: sure if you pass the literal as opposed to a typed variable, i.e. `sum(1L, 2L);` - but why if I'm defining the variable with a type, i.e. `long a = 1(?L); long b = 2(?L); sum(a,b);`?

Comment: In a perfect world, wouldn't the compiler just be able to figure it out based on what the type _should_ be? Of course, this might not be feasible given Java's design, but I don't think it's impossible in general.

Comment: I don't know why they call the grammar "context free", but at least it coincide with the general principle that the meaning of an expression is self evident, not dependent on its context.

Comment: It makes sense if you're thinking of literals in the context of literals. Although, more often than not, I find myself wanting the literal to be the type defined for the variable - it seems redundant to have to specify it in that case.

Comment: @wulfgar.pro designing a programming language close to the intuition of programmers would be very nice; but also very difficult. a feature request seems very simple on its own; but adding it to the spec which already is 700 pages long without breaking anything is not an easy task.

Comment: @irreputable - a context free grammar is one where the results of the parse do not depend on contextual information.  That's fine, but it doesn't mean that the **meaning** of some parse tree doesn't depend on the context.  (That would be nonsensical ...)