# Explicit specification of an integral type, Long

Tags: java

When I execute this code in java:

```
long l = 999_999_999_999;
```

I get the following error,

```
error: integer number too large: 999999999999
        long l = 999_999_999_999;
```

But if I explicitly specify the number as `long` by adding `l` or `L` at the end, the problem disappears.

```
long l = 999_999_999_999L; // Works
```

My question is, why?

I know that all integral literals in java are `integer` by default, but why it would stop java from type casting and accommodating the value in a long, when a long is clearly large enough to hold the literal?

I am looking for some technical details.

Comment: [Reasoning behind having to specify L for long, F,D for float, double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522901/reasoning-behind-having-to-specify-l-for-long-f-d-for-float-double)

Comment: Could Java accomodate this? Absolutely, yes. But it doesn't. That's the `long` and the `short` of it :)

Comment: A puppy dies every time you use the underscore syntax for number literals.

Comment: @asteri I thought the underscore makes look cleaner, at least for this example.

Comment: Yes you are right, the compiler could determine that this is a long literal simply by looking at its range.

However it is specified (JLS 3.10.1) to not do this. I think this is done to avoid problems where users are not aware that they have a too large number they try to assign to an integer anyway. I think it is a bit of a general principle of the language to be not too magic/user friendly. This does make the implementations easier and more robust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly intended.

Think about how the program is parsed. The lexer which splits the Java source into tokens knows about two things of literal:

- the ones which don't end with `[L|l]`
- the ones which end with `[L|l]`

A literal which doesn't have the long specifier at the end is parsed as an integer. This means that the literal itself is invalid because you are not allowed to define an integer literal which is larger than the larger number that you can represent with an `int`.

This is clear in the grammar specification [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); ***otherwise it is of type int*** (§4.2.1).
>
> It is a compile-time error if a decimal literal ***of type int*** is larger than 2147483648 (231), or if the decimal literal 2147483648 appears anywhere other than as the operand of the unary minus operator (§15.15.4).

So even without any assignment, if you have the expression

```
999_999_999_999
```

This is parsed as an integer literal, but its value is over the maximum allowed value, hence it is illegal. The fact that the value of this expression is later assigned to something is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Java won't automatically cast your `int` literal as a `long`, because the `int` literal is invalid in the first place.  That's why `long` literals exist, so values greater in magnitude can be expressed as  literals.

According to the [JLS, Section 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> It is a compile-time error if a decimal literal of type int is larger than 2147483648 (2<sup>31</sup>), or if the decimal literal 2147483648 appears anywhere other than as the operand of the unary minus operator (§15.15.4).

In Java, you simply can't have an `int` literal bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, even if its only use is to assign a value to a `long`.  Bigger literals must be `long` with an `L` suffix to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If your going to understand your problem. You will have to understand how Java reads and assign values to variables.

Java first reads the value that you want to assign to the variable, which is "99999999" then assigns it to the variable.

Without the "L" at the end, Java reads the value of the number, but encounters the problem that it is too big for an int. with the "L" at the end, Java knows it is a Long, therefore it is large enough.